# To-do list app being deleted when checking off an item

Tags: javascript

When I press the circle to the left of an item name, to check an item on the list, the entire list is removed. When I reload the page, the list reappears, with the item I pressed checked, but when I press a circle again all elements are removed. This is an endless loop.

Here is my GUI:
[image: Here is my GUI for context.]

I was not able to find an answer on my own.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```js
const inputBox = document.getElementById("input-box");
const listContainer = document.getElementById("list-container");

function addTask(){
    if (inputBox.value === ''){
        alert("You must write something!");
    }else{
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = inputBox.value;
        listContainer.appendChild(li);
        let span = document.createElement("span");
        span.innerHTML = "\u00d7";
        li.appendChild(span); 
    }
    inputBox.value = "";
    saveData();
}

listContainer.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if(e.target.tagName === "LI"){
        e.target.classList.toggle("checked");
        saveData();
    }else if(e.target.tagName === "SPAN");{
        e.target.parentElement.remove();
        saveData();
    }
}, false);

function saveData(){
    localStorage.setItem("data", listContainer.innerHTML);
}

function showTask(){
    listContainer.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("data");
}
showTask();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We'll need your HTML to test this out.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the correct solution since we only have the JS side of your project, but there is a semicolon right after the `else if` of the `listContainer.addEventListener` function.

Due to this, the code inside the `else if` block always executes regardless of the condition.

Here is the updated code for you to try:

```html
const inputBox = document.getElementById("input-box");
const listContainer = document.getElementById("list-container");

function addTask(){
    if (inputBox.value === ''){
        alert("You must write something!");
    } else {
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = inputBox.value;
        listContainer.appendChild(li);
        let span = document.createElement("span");
        span.innerHTML = "\u00d7";
        li.appendChild(span); 
    }
    inputBox.value = "";
    saveData();
}

listContainer.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if(e.target.tagName === "LI"){
        e.target.classList.toggle("checked");
        saveData();
    } else if(e.target.tagName === "SPAN") {
        e.target.parentElement.remove();
        saveData();
    }
}, false);

function saveData(){
    localStorage.setItem("data", listContainer.innerHTML);
}

function showTask(){
    listContainer.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("data");
}
showTask();
```

Here is a snippet to see the fix in action. Note that this version has the local storage calls removed since Stack Snippets are sandboxed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>To-Do List</title>
<style>
.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="input-box" placeholder="Enter task">
<button onclick="addTask()">Add Task</button>

<ul id="list-container"></ul>

<script>
const inputBox = document.getElementById("input-box");
const listContainer = document.getElementById("list-container");

function addTask(){
    if (inputBox.value === ''){
        alert("You must write something!");
    } else {
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = inputBox.value;
        listContainer.appendChild(li);
        let span = document.createElement("span");
        span.innerHTML = "\u00d7";
        li.appendChild(span); 
    }
    inputBox.value = "";
}

listContainer.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if(e.target.tagName === "LI"){
        e.target.classList.toggle("checked");
    } else if(e.target.tagName === "SPAN") {
        e.target.parentElement.remove();
    }
}, false);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: omg thank you so much, the problem was actually the  semi-colon(;) damn i would have never expected that, thank you

Comment: @StavroStory No problem, glad I could help. If you could mark this as the solution, that would mean a lot!